# C# Dynamic Radio Button Groups from database

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a program that lists members from a database when their membership is about to expire. What I'd like to know is if it is possible to generate and group three radio buttons per member like the example below:

`Member 1 o Renew o Finished o Carry Over`

`Member 2 o Renew o Finished o Carry Over`

`Member 3 o Renew o Finished o Carry Over`

`Member 4 o Renew o Finished o Carry Over`

I will then have a submit button which would update the data for each of the members in regards to which radio button was selected for them.

Thanks

Comment: `What I'd like to know is if it is possible to generate`.. Yes! of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

### ASP.NET

If you're using an ASP.NET application then you just need to set the `GroupName` appropriately. Please take note to this statement [from the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx):

> The buttons are grouped logically if they all share the same GroupName property.

### Windows Forms

If you're using a Windows Forms application then just place each grouping of `RadioButton` controls in their own `GroupBox` or `Panel` and they will be treated as separate groupings. Please take note to this statement [from the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx):

> All RadioButton controls in a given container, such as a Form, constitute a group. To create multiple groups on one form, place each group in its own container, such as a GroupBox or Panel control.

Comment: You're giving a `System.Web.UI` related answer, while the OP is most probably using winforms. That will confuse the OP even more.